# When Using Managed Navigation for Current nav. Opening a page changes the current nav. SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-navigation

My final goal is to have consistent Current Navigation (left nav) across multiple site (collections). Thus the use of Managed Navigation.  We are using Managed Navigation for both Global and Current Nav. I have run into a problem that seems to be a 'featurebug' with SharePoint 2013 (or I am missing a setting (I hope)).

Platform:
SharePoint 2013 - Aug 2015 CU
I have reduced my test to bare bones, without customizations.  Brand new site collection team site with publishing enabled. Create a new wiki page with nothing on the page (blank page) .../SitePages/Testpage.aspx.

I started my test by making a structural navigation similar to what I was going to use for managed navigation as a base.

The structure is:

GlobalHeader1        (points to home page)
          GlobalLink1   (Points to home page)
GlobalHeader2         (Points to home page)
          GlobalLink2   (Points to Testpage.aspx)

CurHeader1            (Header Only - no link)
           CurLink1     (Points to home page)
CurHeader2            (Header Only - no link)
           CurLink2     (Points to Testpage.aspx)

Of course Global items are set in the global tree and Cur items in the Current tree - All works as expected

I also put a link to Testpage.aspx on the home page for testing)  Everything worked as expected. The Current navigation showed all Headers and links as expected and when navigating to the TestPage.aspx using link on page, GlobalLink2 or CurLink2 the TestPage.aspx displayed as desired with the Current navigation as designed above.

Create a Managed Navigation term set as shown above making sure the appropriate boxes are checked to make sure they only show up in either the Global or Current nav but not both. I set both navigation to Managed Navigation selecting the appropriate term set.  The Home page looks great with the expected Global and Current Navigation as desired and as you would expect.

[image: Initial Navigation]
---- Image1 ---

This is where it gets interesting -

If I use any of the methods to open the Testpage.aspx e.g. link on page, GlobalLink2 or CurLink2 the Current navigation reduces to only the CurLink2.

[image: Reduced Current Navigation after page load]
---  Image2 ---

From my project I determined that the Current nav is reducing to the link directly under the heading where the link to the page is found.  For instance I have 4 other links under the same heading and they would all display but non of the other navigation links.  Global Nav does not alter.

But wait! there's more!

If I remove the link CurLink2 (You can remove the link or point it to home page) OR leave CurLink2 as is and add the Testpage.aspx link to CurHeader2 you will find that the page loads as expected without the Current nav being reduced. For my example below and for clarity I simply removed CurLink2 and added the link to CurHeader2. You will see that the Testpage.aspx loads fine with the Current nav intact.  (As mentioned above, I could have simply left CurLink2 with the link to the Testpage and added the Testpage.aspx link to CurHeader2 (both CurHeader2 and CurLink2 have the same link) and all would be well. (Except we want a nicely formatted left nav with headers to group link categories.) The resulting page would have looked like Image1 above.

Can someone tell me if this is a 'featurebug' or is there some way to fix this?

Thank you for any help you can suggest or provide!